# soap connection with sugarcrm and delphi 7

Tags: delphi, soap, sugarcrm

I have created a delphi 7 program and connected to sugarcrm with soap wsdl.
I'm using Tnt Components for their unicode support. Everything works as expected till now.
When I pass a query with a unicode string using

```
get_entry_list(session, 'Accounts',
  '<The unicode string query>',
  'NAME',
  fetchedall,
  sf,
  Trunc(seMaxRes.Value),
   0);
```

nothing returns as result 
The request is as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <NS1:get_entry_list xmlns:NS1="http://www.sugarcrm.com/sugarcrm">
      <session xsi:type="xsd:string">cviljal690kflmq992enth5ps6</session>
      <module_name xsi:type="xsd:string">Accounts</module_name>
      <query xsi:type="xsd:string">Accounts.name like "%ΞΒ£%"</query>
      <order_by xsi:type="xsd:string">NAME</order_by>
      <offset xsi:type="xsd:int">0</offset>
      <select_fields xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array" SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:string[0]"/>
      <max_results xsi:type="xsd:int">25</max_results>
      <deleted xsi:type="xsd:int">0</deleted>
    </NS1:get_entry_list>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

something I'm doing wrong with the encoding of the query parameter.
I've  used the UTF8Encode when passing the query parameter with no lack

Thanks

Comment: Is the problem with the encoding when you build the request (so that the `<query>` does not contain the correct string, or is the problem that SugarCRM doesn't return any records (or an empty response) even though it should? The above request works OK on my SugarCRM, and it returns records if I change the query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK solved. 
Upgrade to delphi XE2 ...

Comment: Does this mean that you still expect a Delphi 7 + TNT component solution (as of the time I comment, you haven't yet accept your own answer/work around)?